# Python 2.7 load and edit list from another python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python file with a lot of code and lists. I need to add column in particular list.

My questions are - how can I load particular list from .py file? And, how can I add element into particular list?

Here in my code:

```
import os, datetime, json

login1 = os.environ["login"].split('\')[1].strip()
login = login1.split('.')[0].strip()
USERID = str(os.environ['USERID'])
header = login + USERID + '.json'

with open("d:\\python\\monitor.py", "r") as infile:

data = infile.readlines()

#here I need to load a "dev_personal_files" list and append additional element
```

Content of monitor.py file

```
#some python code
dev_personal_files = [
'Yura.json',
'Sasha.json'
]       
staging_files = [
#'ple.json',
'retailReleaseServer.json', 
'topaz.json',
'ple2.json',
#'klub.json',
'gaabtMX.json'
]
staging_files2 = [
'retailDemo.json',
'resort.json',
'jhnkljkl.json',
'hbjk,nm,.json',
'bnbnj,jnk,.json'
]
#some python code
```

What I want to add into "dev_personal_files" list (list within monitor.py file):

```
dev_personal_files = [
'NEWRECORD.json',
'Yura.json',
'Sasha.json'
]
```

Comment: What is the format of data? I assume you already tried loading the second file as a infile with a different name and then appending it to the first list with something like `data1.list1.extend(data2.list2)`?

Comment: @kushy format - python file with bunch of lists and some python code. Can you give me an example, how to load list from such file?

Comment: I don't know about the infile stuff. I thought you knew about it since you were using it. Usually, if you put the monitor.py and dev_personal_files.py in the same directory as your main file, you can just import them, as the new answer just now states.

Comment: @kushy - dev_personal_files - its a list within monitor.py file

Comment: Then where is the additional info stored that you wanted to add to the dev_personal_files list? Or were you going to add it to the list during runtime and then save the list again to monitor.py? If yes, you should rather use csv-files, config-files some other data format to save those lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a list (or any object) from a `.py` file is done by importing the file:

```
import mypyfile # <- leave off the .py 

importedlist =  mypyfile.dev_personal_files
```

Or you can just import the object itself:

```
from mypyfile import dev_personal_files

dev_personal_files.extend(my_list_of_extra_items)
```

However the changes to the list will be lost after you end your python session.

If you want to permanently store changes to the list, save it in a format like json, not in a py file.

```
import json

# Read data from the file
with open('myfile.json') as f:
    my_list = json.load(f)

# Add an item to your list
my_list.append('foo')

# Save data to the file
with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_list)
```